# Wordpress - Following users list with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, author

I'm using "[Users Following System](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/)" plugin. So far I added a list of the following/followers into the `author.php` profile, now I'm trying to use Ajax with this but the problem I'm facing that I need to get the same user meta for each user by ID, So that everyone can see the following users of each other.

In `author.php` I used this line to get the users information.

```
<?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>
```

And this line to get the user meta of `_pwuf_following`

```
$include = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);
```

But when I added the same lines within the Ajax function handler not working.

i tried `get_queried_object();`  `wp_get_current_user();`   `get_userdata();`
but I always failing.

Here's the snippet from author.php to get the list of following users.

```
<?php

$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

$include = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);

if ( empty( $include ) ) {

     echo 'Not followed anyone yet.';

    } else {

$args = array (
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include'  => $include,
    'number'  => 52,
    'paged' => 1
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

    echo '<div id="top-artists-contributors-3">';
    echo '<ul id="grid-contributors-4">';
    echo '<li class="scroll-artists">';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $avatar_size = 90;
        $avatar = get_avatar($user->user_email, 200);
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($user->ID);
        $profile = get_userdata($user->ID);

    echo '<div class="single-item-3">';
    echo '<div class="author-gravatar-3"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">', $avatar , '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="members-name"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">' . $profile->first_name .'</a></div>';
    echo '</div>';           
    }
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This is the js to get Ajax url and action

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
var canBeLoaded = true,
bottomOffset = 2000;

jQuery(function($) {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ) {
    canBeLoaded = false;
        var data = {
            'action': 'user_following_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("user_more_following"); ?>'
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#following').append(response);
            canBeLoaded = true;
            page++;
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And this is from the function.php of Ajax handler.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_user_following_by_ajax', 'user_following_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_following_by_ajax', 'user_following_by_ajax_callback');

function user_following_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('user_more_following', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];

$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

$include = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);


if ( empty( $include ) ) {

     echo 'Not followed anyone yet.';

    } else {

$args = array (
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include'  => $include,
    'number'  => 52,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

    echo '<div id="top-artists-contributors-3">';
    echo '<ul id="grid-contributors-4">';
    echo '<li class="scroll-artists">';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $avatar_size = 90;
        $avatar = get_avatar($user->user_email, 200);
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($user->ID);
        $profile = get_userdata($user->ID);

    echo '<div class="single-item-3">';
    echo '<div class="author-gravatar-3"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">', $avatar , '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="members-name"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">' . $profile->first_name .'</a></div>';
    echo '</div>';           
    }
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `get_current_user_id()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah i tried it but nothing happen, can you please give me an answer of what the right way to do it to get the same user meta on the Ajax function and the user following list.

Comment: I don't understand this line in your AJAX callback: `$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));` neither `$author_name` nor `$author` seems to be set, and where does the GET parameter come from, since you do a `$.post`?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, Look I'm newbie with wp and I'm just an artist starts with new multi author site, So all what i did from searching, now i have a small knowledge to insert code but i still can't coding, So, please if you can give me the right code or how can i make it work! btw, this line to took it from author.php trying to get the same user meta from the meta_key `_pwuf_following`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you don't pass the `author_name` field which is used in your code. Please check below code where I have added the missing field.

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
            var page = 2;
            var canBeLoaded = true,
            bottomOffset = 2000;


            jQuery(function($) {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ) {
                canBeLoaded = false;
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'user_following_by_ajax',
                        'data': { page : 'page', author_name: '<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>' }, // Here set author name which you are getting.
                        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("user_more_following"); ?>'
                    };
                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        $('#following').append(response);
                        canBeLoaded = true;
                        page++;
                    });
                }
            });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I added your line but nothing happen, i get "Not followed anyone yet" instead of users, Are the rest of code is ok?

Comment: Here you need to pass the author name in data

Comment: And every time, I scroll up "Not followed anyone yet" is repeating.

Comment: I'm sorry, How can i pass the author name in data, I'm very newbie with wp ;(, and i appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks! But i think the main problem is how to override `$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));` into the Ajax handler function, when i used `$author = wp_get_current_user();` instead.. with `$include = get_user_meta($author->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);` it working with `wp_get_current_user();` but i can't see the following of our users, i see my own following users into their profiles, you get it now?